# Markov Transition Matrix for the Sequence $W W L L L L W L W L L$

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process

I am trying to determine the Markov Transition Matrix for the sequence in the following statement:

> A team in the first 11 games of a championship match has the secuence: $W W L L L L W L W L L$ where $W$ represents a win and $L$ represents a loss.

The only thing I understand properly is that the sum of each row must add up to $1$.

**What I've Tried:**

I tried creating a 2 x 11 matrix where the rows will be a win and a loss and the columns will be for each game but I was told that was incorrect.

How do I go about constructing the Markov Transition Matrix for the above sequence?

Comment: I assume that the transition matrix is supposed to contain the probability that the next outcome is $Y$ on the condition that the current outcome is $X$? In that case it would be a $2\times 2$ matrix, not a $2\times 11$ matrix.

Comment: @Magma The problem does not say.

Comment: Then what does your lecture or course say?

Comment: @Magma I did not get opportunity to have him explain it to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly is meant by the transition matrix for a finite sequence, but maybe it's this:

One of the four W is followed by a W, while three out of four are followed by L;
two of the six L are followed by W, while four out of six are followed by L (there's a seventh L, but it isn't followed by anything);
so the matrix is $$\pmatrix{1/4&3/4\cr1/3&2/3\cr}$$

Comment: Thanks. And now if I want to calculate the percentage of victories that the team will have, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: Surely you have some course materials that explain how to get from the transition matrix to the steady-state distribution? What it boils down to is (if we call that matrix, $A$) finding the vector $v$ such that $vA=v$.

Answer (score 2):

A Markov process is defined by transition *probabilities* between states. In the best case, here you have a finite sample from which you can estimate probabilities.